# 'export' variable not reflecting while runing shell script from groovy

Tags: shell, groovy, scripting, export

Suppose I do
export a='Hi' in linux terminal

```
In groovy script,Code:
def arg='$a/Hello'
def command='sh test.sh $arg'
def process=command.execute().text
println process
```

Output:
**$a/Hello**

```
In shell script, test.sh, I just do echo:
echo $1
```

If I run sh test.sh $a/Hello, then

Output:
**Hi/Hello**

Why in groovy output $a value is not printing, How can I get $a value shown in groovy output?

Comment: You must use double quutes around `a` -> `"$a/Hello"`, singe quotes do not support interpolation